# Django: How to convert string and int into variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have declared a variable as"

```
a1 = 10
```

Now in a function I need to call this variable by adding "a"+"1". However result is a1 in string and not above declared variable.

Here is the code:

```
a1 = 10
b = "a"+"1"
print(b)
a1
```

when I print b, answer is a1, instead of 10. How can I change this concatenate to declared variable?

Comment: Please explain your use case, there may be some better ways to achieve what you are trying to do

Comment: I have 5 different variable and need to update these in a table. Need to loop queryset to update this 5 variables by increasing a1,a2 like this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your requirement. Why don't you edit your OP and explain things in a bit more detail? Someone might have a solution for you.

Comment: Looking at my code it seems valid question. Is there any option to arrive at variable by concatenating str and int? Or its not possible?

Comment: Storing your variables in a list or dict instead may be simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python inbuilt function `eval` for such requirements like below :-

```
>> a1 = 10
>> b = "a"+"1"
>> print(eval(b))
>> 10
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks a lot. Wonderfully same eval() works in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

*if I understand, you want to dynamically create the name of a variable and access it :*
you can use `dict` for that i think

```
a1, a2, a3 = 10, 11, 12
var_dict = {'a1': a1, 'a2': a2, 'a3': a3}

for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    print(var_dict[f"a{i}"])  # f"a{i}" => 'a1', 'a2', 'a3' according to i value
```

Comment: This is workaround. Correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/69698328/6303199

Answer (score 0):

The statement `b = 'a'+'1'` means that your new variable `b` is a string:

```
>>> b = ['a1']
```

If you are interested in printing a1, you have just to do:

```
print(a1)
```

Making a sum of the letters of a declared variable does not result in the variable itself.

Comment: There is no way to arrive at variable? cant we convert it to variable?

Comment: @PulkitSharma you could make a list of those variables and loop it inside your function